# How to do dependency injection on complex classes like when extending WidgetBase

Tags: 8, dependency-injection

Since the Drupal sniffer whines at you if you call `\Drupal::service()` in your code, I have been trying to figure out how to use dependency injection on a widget  I’ve been working on. Here’s what I’ve currently arrived at:

```
<?php

use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldDefinitionInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\WidgetBase;
use Drupal\xois\SicsService;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class XoisSicSelect extends WidgetBase {

  /**
  * SICs service.
  *
  * @var \Drupal\xois\SicsService
  */
  protected $sicsService;

  /**
  * {@inheritdoc}
  */
  public function __construct($plugin_id, $plugin_definition, FieldDefinitionInterface $field_definition, array $settings, array $third_party_settings, SicsService $sicsService) {
    parent::__construct($plugin_id, $plugin_definition, $field_definition, $settings, $third_party_settings);
    $this->sicsService = $sicsService;
  }

  /**
  * {@inheritdoc}
  */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('xois.sics')
    );
  }

}
```

Pretty much the standard DI pattern, no? Only difference is that WidgetBase takes a whole load of construct parameters already.
Problem is, it doesn’t work. When run, it gives this delightful error:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Recoverable fatal error: Argument 6 passed to Drupal\xois\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\XoisSicSelect::__construct() must be an instance of Drupal\xois\SicsService, none given, called in /var/www/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Field/WidgetPluginManager.php on line 125 and defined in Drupal\xois\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\XoisSicSelect->__construct() (line 35 of modules/xois/src/Plugin/Field/FieldWidget/XoisSicSelect.php).
```

Anyone got an idea on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to implement `ContainerFactoryPluginInterface` in order to use dependency injection in your class.

Include `use Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface;` and implement the interface so it looks like:

```
class XoisSicSelect extends WidgetBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {

    ....

}
```

You will also need to make sure your `__construct()` and `create()` methods contain the correct parameters.

If you look at `ContainerFactoryPluginInterface.php`, you will see the parameters the `create()` method takes in:

```
public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
```

Thus, your final code should look like:

```
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldDefinitionInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\WidgetBase;
use Drupal\xois\SicsService;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface;

class XoisSicSelect extends WidgetBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {
  /**
   * SICs service.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\xois\SicsService
   */
  protected $sicsService;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function __construct($plugin_id, $plugin_definition, FieldDefinitionInterface $field_definition, array $settings, array $third_party_settings, SicsService $sicsService) {
    parent::__construct($plugin_id, $plugin_definition, $field_definition, $settings, $third_party_settings);
    $this->sicsService = $sicsService;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $configuration['field_definition'],
      $configuration['settings'],
      $configuration['third_party_settings'],
      $container->get('xois.sics')
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This was a difficult one for myself as well. How I figured out to resolve it was to go to the documentation page for the class (ex [WidgetBase](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21WidgetBase.php/class/WidgetBase/8.2.x)), and look for  the __construct() method (ex [WidgetBase::__construct()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21WidgetBase.php/function/WidgetBase%3A%3A__construct/8.2.x)). Click on that, and you'll see a section for "X methods override CLASSNAME::__construct()". For example, DateRangeDefaultWidget::__construct overrides WidgetBase::__construct(). Click on the override, and you'll an example of what the __construct() override should look like:

```
public function __construct($plugin_id, $plugin_definition, FieldDefinitionInterface $field_definition, array $settings, array $third_party_settings, EntityStorageInterface $date_storage) {
  parent::__construct($plugin_id, $plugin_definition, $field_definition, $settings, $third_party_settings);

  $this->dateStorage = $date_storage;
}
```

And if you look at the class page (ex [DateRangeDefaultWidget](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21datetime_range%21src%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldWidget%21DateRangeDefaultWidget.php/class/DateRangeDefaultWidget/8.2.x)), you can find what the create() method should look like: [DateRangeDefaultWidget::create](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21datetime_range%21src%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldWidget%21DateRangeDefaultWidget.php/function/DateRangeDefaultWidget%3A%3Acreate/8.2.x)):

```
public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
  return new static(
  $plugin_id, 
  $plugin_definition, 
  $configuration['field_definition'], 
  $configuration['settings'], 
  $configuration['third_party_settings'], 
  $container->get('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('date_format')
  );
}
```

So it takes a bit of detective work, but once you figure out the method of detecting, it's actually fairly straightforward for any classes.

Comment: Your IDE/code editor should be able to help with this. For example, when a method is being overridden Netbeans looks up the parent and displays a clickable marker next to the line number. Clicking on the marker will open the file with the parent method and take you to it.

Comment: Depends on the editor. Mine doesn't do this.

Comment: It's a handy feature. Obviously the whole Drupal codebase needs to be part of the same project for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the create() method and add your argument, not replace it.

There's no magic involved, it's just a plain static PHP method that contructs an object, including all its arguments.